# How to create a bar plot of this table

Tags: r, datatable, bar-chart

Here is a random simplified table I created but similar to what I really have. The real one has more parties (columns) and areas.

[image]

It shows the areas of New York and the voting percentages for each political party in the area.

I want to create a bar plot in R for each party where on the x-axis are voting percentages in thresholds and on the y-axis there is the number of areas which has voted that percentage.

Here's a drawing I made of the plot I want to have.

[image]

For example, for voting percentages between 2-3%, there is one are which has that voting percentage and so on. However, I don't know how to create this since I don't know how to count the number of areas which fall into that voting percentage threshold (the real data is a lot bigger) and then match it to the x-axis.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(Republicans = c(0.035, 0.034, 0.083, 0.078, 0.092),
                 Democrats =   c(0.023, 0.044, 0.067, 0.083, 0.101))
rownames(df) <- c("Bronx", "Brooklyn", "Manhattan", "Queens", "Staten Island")

# Transformation
freq <- table(floor(c(df[[1]], df[[2]])*100))
barplot(freq, names = names(freq))
```

Next time, please do not post an image (like @r2evans asked).